# Script detects and runs when USB Drive with unique serial number is connected

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

Script should run when it detects USB drive with specific serial number is just plugged in.

But its giving this error msg:

> { Cannot convert value "Win32_PhysicalMedia='K:'" to type "System.Management.ManagementObject". Error: "Not found " }

Here is the script:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier
volumeChange
do{
$newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
$eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
$eventTypeName = switch($eventType)
{
1 {"Configuration changed"}
2 {"Device arrival"}
3 {"Device removal"}
4 {"docking"}
}

if ($eventType -eq 2)
{
$driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
$driveSerial = ([wmi]"Win32_PhysicalMedia='$driveLetter'").SerialNumber

if ($driveSerial -eq '0401541bbf5130dceb26')
{
    msg * USB IS PLUGGED IN
}
}
Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
} while (1-eq1) 
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a big comment...

While I won't be of much help, see if you can replace the current line to get `$driveSerial` by the following

```
$drive_serialnumber = Get-Partition -DriveLetter $driveLetter  | Get-Disk | select-object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
$drive_serialnumber.trim()
```

Source - Answer by Robin at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590453/obtain-disk-serial-number-from-drive-letter

I just tried it and it seems to be somehow working.
I got one error but it did display the Serialnumber.

See the following attempt as a screenshot.

Hope you will be able to build on this further.

[image]

---

Edit 1

I found the source of error, `DriveLetter equal to :` the Drive Letter contains ":".
So trim it before using it in the code.

I used something like

```
$TrimmedLetter = $driveLetter.TrimEnd(":")
```

---

Edit 2

Here's my sample code snippet that seem to be working fine at my end on Windows 11 PC.

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
do{
$newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
$eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
$eventTypeName = switch($eventType)
{
1 {"Configuration changed"}
2 {"Device arrival"}
3 {"Device removal"}
4 {"docking"}
}

if ($eventType -eq 2)

{
# Set constant. Replace this with your own value in UpperCase.
$Const_Ser_Num = "1F5A1F0044CE" 
# Get the drive letter
$driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
# Remove ':' from the end of it
$TrimmedLetter = $driveLetter.TrimEnd(":")
# Get the serial number for the drive letter
$drive_serialnumber = Get-Partition -DriveLetter $TrimmedLetter  | Get-Disk | select-object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
$drive_serialnumber = $drive_serialnumber.Trim()
write-host $drive_serialnumber  # <--For testing only
if ($drive_serialnumber.ToUpper() -eq $Const_Ser_Num)
   {
      #rest of your code....
      write-host ("Pen drive found")  # <--For testing only
   }

}
Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
} while (1-eq1) 
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

Note the following

- The test pen drive at my end has serialNumber as `1F5A1F0044CE` This value is set to $Const_Ser_Num in Uppercase letters
- I am not PowerShell expert, there could be inadvertent errors in this code
- I do not know if `-eq` for string is case sensitive or not. So use ToUpper() to be on safer side

[image]

Comment: Hi, thankyou very much for your script. Where in the script do I put the $TrimmedLetter ?

Comment: See Edit 2 above